# Spring Batch Java annotated - restart example

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Using the Spring Boot, Batch example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Project is now running, but the site doesn't go into how to write Unit tests around this structure. Github examples for Spring Batch show xml examples, which do not seem to correlate to this boot style.

Has anyone ran into any good Spring Boot, Batch examples that show restarting, unit testing, etc

Answer (score 0):

The reference documentation was recently updated to provide java based configuration examples for every example in the doc.  You can check out our testing page and see the java examples here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing